# How to access a current state in another component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to access this user set in another component. I passed the state down from the highest component(which is app) using this function to change state.

```
  handleRegisterSubmit(e, username, password) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/auth/register', {
      username,
      password,
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.user.id)
      this.setState({  
        auth: res.data.auth,
        user: res.data.user,
        currentPage: 'selectSources',
      });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

After that hits the model in the backend it brings me back a response which is where i change the user state from null to a object with the user information.

I then pass that information to the home component.

```
renderHomeIfloggedin(){
  if (this.state.auth){
    console.log(this.state.user)
    return  <Home auth={this.state.auth} userInfo={this.state.user}/>
  }
}
```

inside the home component i hit this function

```
renderSelectSources(){
    if (!this.state.dataLoaded){
      console.log(this.props.userInfo,'djfosidjfodisj')
        return (
     <div>
       {this.props.user}
       <SelectSources user={this.props.userInfo} test={this.returnSources}/>
       </div>)
    }
}
```

i then try to access the user object from the app component using props. and pas it to the Selectsources component.

inside of the select sources component I want to post the news object along with the user object and send it to the backend. The news object is being sent fine, but im struggling to access the current state. When i look in the react developer tools, the user state is the information that i wanted, but the props information is undefined when i console log it for some reason.

```
handleClick(source_object) {
  console.log(source_object,'ioefjsoejfoi',this.props.user);
  axios.post('/news', {
    source: source_object,
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log("Posted"+ source_object.source.name);
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The screenshot shows that the user object is still the current state, so i am not sure where i went wrong.

[image]

Comment: you have two props related to same thing, `user` and `userInfo`. check if there any typo on it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is about what `this` is in the method `handleClick`,by its name I assume that method is some kind of callback of a button when is pressed, so when that method is called on a click event the `this` object is no longer pointing to the `this` of your SelectSources class (Where your userInfo is)

To fix this issue you have to bind your method in the constructor of the SelectSources class

```
class SelectSources extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    // Make sure the handleClick method is always pointing to the this of this class
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); 
  }
}
```